# Need help on my jquery code: fade in and out to new image

Tags: jquery

I need help on fading in and out 3 images. Once the third image fades out the page will redirect.

```
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Example" id="slideshow" />
<script>
$(function() {

$('#slideshow').fadeIn(3000, function() {
$(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000, function() { window.location = 'http://google.com/'; });
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the 3 images a common class (eg: slideshow).

```
var images = $('.slideshow'), len = images.length;

images.each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i*6000).fadeIn(3000, function() {
     $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
         if (i === len - 1) window.location = 'http://google.com/';           
     });
  });
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ppLNh/)***

Comment: Works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks!